# Want to add _ under my string

Tags: javascript

I am writing a Web Scrawler to retrieve information from a website, my code is like below

```
var request=require("request");
var cheerio=require("cheerio");

var url="http://www.cwb.gov.tw/V7e/forecast/taiwan/Taipei_City.htm";

request(url,function(err,res,body){
   if(err){
       console.log("Error happened!"+err);
   } 
   else{
       console.log("Status Code "+res.statusCode);
       var $=cheerio.load(body);

       let cities = []
       $('.CenterMenu option').each(function(i, elem) {
       cities.push($(this).text().split('\n')[0]);
      })
     url="http://www.cwb.gov.tw/V7e/forecast/taiwan/inc/city/"+cities[0]+".htm";

       }     
 });
```

what I want is I can print the cities string like Changhua_City, however, the cities I print always be like Changhua city, would like to know what would be possible to fix this line `cities.push($(this).text().split('\n')[0]);`to let my cities array looked like Changua_City

Comment: Would a [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace) of a space with an underscore help?

Comment: You saved my life, thanks!

Comment: Try accessing the attribute instead of text value - `cities.push($(this).attr('value').split('.')[0]);`

Comment: Hi for those who face the same problem, all these comments help, you can use which one you want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```js
const city = $(this).text().split('\n')[0];
city.replace(/(\ (.{1}))/, (m, s1, s2) => `_${s2.toUpperCase()}`);
cities.push($(this).text().split('\n')[0]
```